# Why can I not use append to create an array in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have the following simple example:

```
struct Test {
    var id:Int
    var text:String
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var array = [Test]()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            ForEach(0...3, id:\.self){ key in
                let test = Test(id: key, text: "Testing")
                array.append(test)
          
            }
}}
```

I am getting the error message:
Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
If I delete the array.append line then the error message disappears. So, in Swift this would work like great, but in SwiftUI this seems to be different . Can somebody please explain why and how I can achieve the creation of the array by adding elements through a loop.

Comment: `ForEach` is a view container, not control flow operator.

Comment: OK, so, is there another way of creating the array in SwiftUI?

Comment: actually, using a func would solve the issue . Using "for key in 1...5 {}"

Comment: I did not realise that ForEach is not to be used as foreach in Swift. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is simple demo

[image: demo]

```
struct Test: Identifiable {
    var id:Int
    var text:String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var array: [Test] = (0...3).map { Test(id: $0, text: "Testing") }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(array) { test in
                Text("\(test.id): \(test.text)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use a for loop (`for i in 0...3 in {}`) in an initializer to create your array instead of `(0...3).map {}`